# watermarking of render_to_string using wickedpdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn, wicked-pdf

I am generating a PDF document from HTML using `render_to_string` and Wicked PDF gem and I want to do watermarking of generated document. For watermarking I am using Prawn and I am watermarking diagonally and even the text could be of variable length so I have to calculate bounds but generated PDF by Wicked PDF gives me incorrect dimensions/bounds using Prawn however any other PDF generated by some reader gives me correct bounds. Is there any way to set bounds in generated PDF or an other way to watermark?

This is the code for generating the PDF:

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string(
  :pdf => "some.pdf",
  :template => 'some.pdf.haml'),
  :margin => { 
    :top                => 18,                    
    :bottom             => 6,
    :left               => 0,
    :right              => 0
  },
  :page_size => 'A4', 
  :orientation => 'Landscape'
  :encoding=>"UTF-8",   
  :footer => { :content => render_to_string(:template => 'layouts/shared/footer.pdf.haml') },
  :header => { :content => render_to_string(:template => 'layouts/shared/header.pdf.haml') }
)
```

I want to mark that generated PDF, but it is giving me very odd behaviour like when I calculate its bounds using Prawn and stroke it, it gives me a very small bounded area at the top left corner and that bounded area basically shows that this is the page size and the watermark is only in that area.

Below is the code:

```
input_filename = tmp_filename
output_filename = save_to

page_count = PDF::Reader.new(input_filename).page_count

Prawn::Document.generate(output_filename, :skip_page_creation => true) do |pdf|

  page_count.times do |num|
    pdf.start_new_page(:template => input_filename, :template_page => num + 1)
    pdf.stroke_bounds
  end
end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain a little more, and provide some code to show how you are watermarking and getting bounds? You should know ahead of time what page size your pdf is by informing wicked_pdf to use A3 or Letter.

Comment: @Unixmonkey in short form wickedpdf is generating corrupted pdfs.:S

Comment: `wicked_pdf` mostly only ties Rails rendering to the `wkhtmltopdf` command. What version of `wkhtmltopdf` are you using? It seems that 0.9.6 may be creating PDFs that don't strictly follow the spec: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/282 Try using a newer version of `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: its 0.9.9.1 .:( and there is another problem. when i zoom the document via wickedpdf the html links missplaced. the remains in their place when i readjut the document.